# How to find inertial advective component of ageostrophic wind in natural coordinates

Tags: meteorology, wind

How do you derive the components of the inertial advective wind in natural coordinates?

The vector form of the inertial advective wind is:

[image]

I have been able to find the components in cartesian coordinates as shown here:

[image]

I want to find the components in natural coordinates (such as shown below), but I have been unsuccessful so far.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you can start by taking a look at my answer here - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12353/centrifugal-force-in-the-navier-stokes-equations/16767#16767

Comment: Can you provide a source for (1) and (2) ?

Comment: I can show how to get Equation (2) but not equation (1). You may have the terms wrong. The second equation should give you the normal component of the ageostrophic wind  - https://climate.ucdavis.edu/ATM121/AtmosphericDynamics-Chapter03-Part02-BalancedFlow.pdf

Comment: Hi for reference the first equation comes from 

Rochette 2006, "A primer of the ageostrophic wind," (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.663.2094&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

 And the second equation comes from the Encyclopedia of Atmospheric Sciences (2nd edition) volume 5 under the entry on Jet Streaks - a preview with the relevant equation can be found here under the heading "SYNOPTIC METEOROLOGY | Jet Streaks" https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/ageostrophic-flow